# URL Rewrite htaccess. Change from id to alias

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to change a working `.htaccess` code that uses the ID as parameter to a name, so I can have a more friendly URL.

For example I would like to have

> myurl.com/pagina/page-name

instead of

> myurl.com/pagina/1

This is the working code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# redirect "/pagina.php?id=xxx" to "/pagina/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pagina\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pagina/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/pagina/xxx" to "/pagina.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^pagina/([0-9]+)$ actagov/pagina.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I tried to change it to

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# redirect "/pagina.php?alias=xxx" to "/pagina/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pagina\.php\?alias=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pagina/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/pagina/xxx" to "/pagina.php?alias=xxx"
RewriteRule ^pagina/([^&\s]+)$ actagov/pagina.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

PHP file

```
if(isset($_GET['alias']))
{
    if(!empty($_GET['alias']))
    {
        $alias_pagina = $_GET['alias'];
        $result_pagina = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE 
nome='$alias_pagina'");
        $query_pagina = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_pagina);
        $id_pagina = $query_pagina['id'];
        $id_template = $query_pagina['id_template'];
        switch($id_template)
        {
            case '1':
            include 'page_template_standard.php';
            break;

            case '2':
            include 'page_template_two_column.php';
            break;
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
else
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

But it's not redirecting at all. I'm probably mistaking the syntax, but I'm not very familiar with the **htaccess** language. Can you tell me what I should change?

EDIT: I finally found the working solution

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 

# redirect "pagina.php?alias=xxx" to "/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pagina\.php\?alias=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /actagov/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/xxx" to "pagina.php?alias=xxx"
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pagina.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

This will transform the url

> localhost/actagov/pagina.php?alias=alias-name

into

> localhost/actagov/alias-name

Comment: If you are requesting `/page/page-name`, then you can probably wait for that to match `^pagina/…` all day, don’t you think? And you are not _grouping_ your match either, so you will not have a `$1` available in the replacement.

Comment: no I just used the first url as an example, the actual URL in the code is what I'm using. My bad to create confusion, anyway how do I go about grouping?

Comment: You start by _researching_ that keyword, if it means nothing to you yet.

Comment: If you mean the round parenthesis, I added them, but it's still not working

Comment: Enable and check the rewrite log. Everyone can just guess here without seeing the actual request paths, or some details on if you really adapted any links to use `?alias=` instead of `?id=` now. (See also: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772) and [How to debug Apache mod\_rewrite](//stackoverflow.com/q/9632852))

Comment: No rewrite rule will be able to magically translate "1" to "page-name"…

Comment: I added the PHP file for more details. Also mod_rewrite and htaccess are already enabled on the Apache server